# How to use the ARG instruction of Dockerfile for Windows image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I would like to pass an argument in my dockerfile to build my docker image. I've seen in other post and docker manual how to do this but it doesn't work in my case. 
Here is an extract of my code where i use my argument:

```
ARG FirefoxVersion
RUN powershell -Command iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
RUN choco install -y firefox --version $FirefoxVersion --ignore-checksums
```

I build my image with this command in powershellPrompt :

```
docker build -t myimage --build-arg FirefoxVersion=61.0.1 .
```

Finally I have this error :

```
 '$FirefoxVersion' is not a valid version string.
 Parameter name: version
 The command 'cmd /S /C choco install -y firefox --version $FirefoxVersion  -- ignore-checksums' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is someone know what is wrong with my code? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(This answer is the formalized version of my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268105/pass-argument-in-dockerfile-to-build-image/53268390#comment93445783_53268390).)

Try to use **%FirefoxVersion%**

```
ARG FirefoxVersion
RUN powershell -Command iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
RUN choco install -y firefox --version %FirefoxVersion% --ignore-checksums
```

#### Reason:

The error message *"The command 'cmd /S /C choco install ...' returned a non-zero code: 1"* indicates that the `choco install` command is executed on cmd.exe (Windows' Command Prompt). Dockerfile's `ARG` value can be treated as an environment variable. On cmd.exe, `%...%` stands for env var.

Comment: This answer provided me with some insights regargin "current shell" and environment variable syntax, however I dont understand why Docker wouldn't perform variable substitution on $FirefoxVersion since this variable substitution sems to occur in other contexts, ex: ARG bar \n ENV foo=$bar where it seems to be working?

Comment: @EmilG It depends on which Dockerfile instruction is used.
When `ENV` used, docker substitues variables.
When `RUN` used, shell (cmd, powershell, bash, etc.) does that.
For more information, see the [Environment replacement section](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) in the Dockerfile reference.

Answer (score 29):

As @matt9 suggested

Use `$env:FirefoxVersion` in powershell

Use `%FirefoxVersion%` in cmd.exe

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016
ARG FirefoxVersion
#if using powershell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
RUN Write-Host Powershell: $env:FirefoxVersion
#if using CMD
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN echo cmd.exe: %FirefoxVersion%
```

Build: `docker build -t myimage --build-arg FirefoxVersion=61.0.1 .`

Result

```
Powershell: 61.0.1
cmd.exe: 61.0.1
```

Comment: An improvement on this answer is `$($Env:FirefoxVersion)` is a better version of the form as it allows you to embed variables in complex commands - consider the following: `Remove-Item python-$($Env:PYTHON_VERSION).exe -Force`

Comment: This literally does not work.  It outputs "Powershell: " << blank. And it outputs: "cmd.exe : %FirefoxVersion%" << literal string.

Comment: @Triynko move the ARG after the SHELL command

Answer (score 3):

Just to add onto @Andy Joiner's answer:

I could not get `$env:<arg name>` to work, the key was moving the `ARG` declaration *AFTER* the `SHELL` command.

Answer (score -2):

Try like this :

Pass arguments like **${FirefoxVersion}**

```
ARG FirefoxVersion
RUN powershell -Command iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'));
RUN choco install -y firefox --version ${FirefoxVersion} --ignore-checksums
```

build docker image :

```
docker build -t --build-arg FirefoxVersion=61.0.1 myimage .
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried but I have the same error    `'${FirefoxVersion}' is not a valid version string.` I don't understand where is the issue..

Comment: Pass argument with double quotes like docker build -t --build-arg FirefoxVersion="61.0.1" myimage .

Comment: @M.Eva Try to use `$env:FirefoxVersion` or `%FirefoxVersion%` instead of `${FirefoxVersion}` in the line of `RUN choco install...` . The former is PowerShell env var expression. The latter is cmd.exe.