# Access Gitlab CI variable during Docker build

Tags: windows, docker, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab

I want to use API tokens stored as Gitlab secret variables in my docker file to build a windows container.

The needed API token is stored as secret variable in Gitlab. A build job will be executed and passes this token to my docker build command as build argument:

```
docker build $MemoryParameters $Env:DOCKER_BUILD_ADDITIONAL_ARGUMENTS
    --pull `
    --build-arg CI_TOKEN=$Env:CI_TOKEN `
    -t $TempImageName .
```

Accessing the variable with `$Env:CI_TOKEN` works as intended.

Trying to reference it in my docker file:

```
ARG CI_TOKEN

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8

//Some RUN commands

RUN  echo "token= %CI_TOKEN%"
```

`%CI_TOKEN%` in the docker file will not be replaced by it's actual value stored in Gitlab.

How should it be referenced?

I'm not quite sure about the interpreter of the base image, but I assume cmd rather than powershell.

Comment: Did you test using [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56797684/2653911) synthax ?

Comment: Tested the dockerfile locally, invoking ˋdocker buildˋ via powershell and calling ˋ%CI_TOKEN%ˋ via ˋRUNˋ from within the dockerfile. All works as expected.